# How to make a button exclusive to a user?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm making an app in android studio for a parking lot where the user simply clicks a green imageview  to ocupy the desired spot and the imageview should turn red and shouldn't let other users click on the imageview.

I already created a login page with firebase and everything is working fine except when you change activities the color from the imageview doesn't stay red and I don't know how to make an imageview that can only be clicked by the user who has already occupied that spot.

Comment: Well you need to keep track of the fact that the user is the one who selected it, and other users should know that they are not the user who selected it.

Comment: can you please share code snippet ?

Comment: I would recommend , If you are using an database for storing the data take a column which stores occupancy status  and make it true or false according to the inputs to the users and load the data on the activities onCreate so that it gets updated every time the activity is loaded. If the app is totally offline try using view models

Comment: @SayokMajumder My app is totally online, but how would you store that data on the database?

Comment: Think there is 2 floors of the parking lot. So make 2 tables for each floor.Each floor table will have 3 columns: 'id','user id', 'acquired'. Now let take 1st floor. Suppose there are 10 parking slots. So table for the 1st floor will have 10 rows. Each row will have a unique id and all the data in the 'acquired' column will be 0. Now suppose the user enters the parking lot. User opens the app and selects slot 5 on 1st floor. Now get the user id from the app and put it in the table of 1st floor row 5 and make acquired to 1 from 0. And when the user leaves revert it to 0.

Comment: And yes in the app part keep a check if the slot 'acquired' column is 0 or 1

Comment: @SayokMajumder I managed to do it thanks to your help, thank you so much!